# Recovering private mode pictures from locked out s6? PIN required on reboot?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, data-recovery, locked-out

I got an s7 and transferred all of my pictures from my old s6, but the ones from private mode didn't transfer over (I don't think I had private mode on on the s7). Now I've realized I don't have all of my pictures, so I dug up my old s6 but for some reason I can't use my fingerprint; it's requiring me to put in the PIN and I can't remember what it is. Honestly I don't even really remember setting one. I've exhausted the following solutions:

-My Samsung account is on my s7 now, so I can't use Samsung's FindMyMobile.
-USB debugging is turned off, so I can't use adb
-The recovery mode is stock, so I can't use a file manager or get adb working that way
-The phone is connected to wifi, but the forgot pattern where I enter my google account isn't showing up for some reason.

Is there any way to copy the pictures, enable usb debugging, or get the google account credential screen to show up?